# Game demo that leverages cluster computing in an easily understandable way

Tags: game, clustering

I am looking for a game demo that leverages cluster computing in an easily understandable way.

At the demo, highschool students looking at the screens of the computers in the cluster would think:

> Oh, THAT would be hard to do that with a single computer... now I understand with clustering is useful!

As a game in order to make the exhibit fun and attractive.

Is there any such game?

Free or open source if possible.

Comment: What is "the real example of cluster computing"?

Comment: This question is far too vague. I recommend reading our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: @unor real example means real application, something that really use many computer to compute, for example Google's Search Engine

Comment: @Gilles yeah, my boss asked me to show a game demo about cluster computing that could impress a highschool students -_-" I have no idea indeed.. usually computer cluster used for technical computation for example CFD (OpenFOAM), or just serving websites with too many requests.. oh well..

Comment: @Kokizzu, I heavily modified your question to try and make it on topic, could you please review and edit if needed? Thanks!

Comment: I removed "real application" because some people think that games are not real applications.

Comment: @Kokizzu as you already indicated, games don't usually fall into the domain of problems that can only / easier be solved with CC. In order to leverage the advantages of a cluster, a problem needs to be highly parallelizable. The only thing I could think of where this applies to games would be some server components ([maybe AI pathfinding / navmesh creation](http://bit.ly/1qNcRpd)) in a game with a client/server architecture. But even then, if a cluster were to be a requirements, the game wouldn't be commercially viable. And if it's not a requirement, it's not that good an example.

Comment: So I would much rather pick a real problem that can be solved in a highly parallelized fashion. There is an excellent article in IEEE spectrum: [The Trouble With Multicore](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/the-trouble-with-multicore/). Especially the example it describes of [how to parallelize the computation of PI](http://spectrum.ieee.org/image/1627665) I found very helpful for how to think about problems in order to be able to parallelize them. So it shouldn't be too hard to create a visual GUI client that shows how nodes contribute their partial solutions to that problem.